# Как или чем разбить по отдельным выгруженный полный экспорт баз данных?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Сделал экспорт всех баз данных с phpmyadmin. Теперь стоит задача как этот весь довольно объемный файл разбить по частям по базам. Что посоветуете? Писать собственный парсер, дергать ручками или уже есть готовое решение?

Comment: В общем случае дамп вообще не делится. *Что посоветуете?* Восстановить как есть на локальном хосте, а затем изготовить бэкапы отдельных БД. И нафиг phpmyadmin - всё только с помощью mysqldump.

Comment: как не делиться? там же просто инструкции создать базу добавить строку

Comment: Ню-ню... достаточно из таблицы одной БД иметь внешний ключ в таблицу другой БД, или использовать функцию, определённую в другой БД - и будет тебе счастье после разделения...